# Google Analytics Custom Variables not reporting

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'x']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'business_id', 5, 3]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

I'm really not sure why they aren't coming across in GA. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. The output for custom variables must be contained within quotes even if it's and integer.

Comment: Is it true that it takes 2 days for the data to show in async mode? I also didn't use quotes but it doesn't seem like solving the problem.